# Is there a specific media query for an ultra wide screen?

Tags: css

My website works on all mobile devices and desktops up to 5120px in width, I used media queries for portrait and landscape versions on my phone and the landscape worked perfectly for laptops and PCs alongside "min-width". However now that I'm dealing with an ultra wide monitor the bottom of my container gets cut off by the bottom of the screen. The media queries I have used so far go like this:

> @media (min-width: 540px) and (orientation:landscape)
>
> @media (min-width: 540px) and (orientation:portrait)

I used the width of the device in either landscape or portrait alongside its orientation and was happy with the results despite the effort, now Im stuck wondering what to use for most ultrawide devices to work?

Comment: Just increase the pixel size constraint?

Comment: Each major browser can handle width and height values of over a million `px`, so yeah, I would just increase the size constraints of your `@media` declarations.

Comment: My guess is you need the [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio) media feature. For example, `@media (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {...}` for screens that are (at least) twice as wide as they are high.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this query and it works like a charm.

```
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
  [CSS]
}
```

You can tweak your ratios as u want, combine the query condition with another property `max-aspect-ratio` or just `aspect-ratio`.

[Browsers support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_media_aspect-ratio) is great.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
@media (min-width: 540px) and (orientation:landscape)
```

so just change it to be

```
@media (min-width: 5120px) and (orientation:landscape)
```

That `min-width` pixel value means "when the screen is at least this wide" so that new query will happen when the screen is `5120px` or wider.

You can leave off the `and (orientation:landscape)` part if you want. Orientation is less of a concern on desktop web browsers, but an OS can send the information about which way the monitor is set up in the display preferences.